# Why I can't chat on SO even though I have enough reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, chat

I tried to join the c# chat, but it keeps telling me that I don't have enough reputation to chat.

I do have enough reputation though.

I saw some similar questions, but none of them seemed to apply to me:

[Chat indicates that I don't have enough reputation to participate, even though I clearly do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117862/chat-indicates-that-i-dont-have-enough-reputation-to-participate-even-though-i)

[Unable to chat after the 20 reputation on stack overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148593/unable-to-chat-after-the-20-reputation-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 5):

You had two chat users (your account was merged a couple years back, and that resulted in an orphaned chat user). Once Marc fixed that, your chat profile was able to synchronize with your main-site profile - you should be able to use chat without further issues now.

For future reference (if anyone else encounters something like this), you can usually identify this problem by [searching chat users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users) - if there are two users with the same main-site account linked, things will probably break.

Answer (score 2):

For some odd reason your [chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1161710/thepaulpage) is not synchronized with your actual account:

> [image]

So as far as the chat knows, you have 1 rep.

I fear only a dev can fix this, just clarified what is wrong.